# Connecting to CRM 2016 IFD in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, crm

I would like to connect to CRM 2016 server using PowerShell cmdlet `Get-CrmConnection` included in the SDK.

**I am having trouble finding the correct connection string.**

Connecting to the server in in the local network works normally:

```
Get-CrmConnection -ConnectionString "Url=http://<server>/OrganizationName;"
```

But connecting to the server configured for IFD fails:

```
Get-CrmConnection -ConnectionString "Url=https://crm.ourdomain.com/"

Get-CrmConnection : Organization cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: Organization Name
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-CrmConnection -ConnectionString "Url=https://crm.ourdomain.com/ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SyntaxError: (:) [Get-CrmConnection], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -9,Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.Powershell.Commands.GetCrmConnectionCommand
```

I tried adding AuthType parameter in the connection string, providing Organization name, but no success. Important thing is that I can connect using the interactive mode:

```
Get-CrmConnection -InteractiveMode
```

[image: Interactive mode window]

This returns the following connection:

```
IsReady                        : True
IsBatchOperationsAvailable     : True
Authority                      :
OAuthUserId                    :
ActiveAuthenticationType       : AD
OrganizationServiceProxy       : Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc+ManagedTokenOrganizationServiceProxy
OrganizationWebProxyClient     :
LastCrmError                   : OrganizationWebProxyClient is null
LastCrmException               :
CrmConnectOrgUriActual         : https://crm.ourdomain.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
ConnectedOrgFriendlyName       : OrganizationName
ConnectedOrgUniqueName         : OrganizationName
ConnectedOrgPublishedEndpoints : {[WebApplication, https://crm.ourdomain.com/], [OrganizationService,
                             https://crm.ourdomain.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc],
                             [OrganizationDataService,
                             https://crm.ourdomain.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc]}
ConnectionLockObject           : System.Object
ConnectedOrgVersion            : 8.0.1.79
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some big gotchas with the `microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector` `CrmConnection` that can have you banging your head against the wall.

To quote from http://crmtipoftheday.com/2016/01/14/rumors-about-microsoft-xrm-client-death-are-exaggerated/

> Note the following:
>
> - Url must be in the form of https://orgname.contoso.com/orgname. For    on-premises and IFD deployments the connector expects orgname to be
>     at the end and looks like it does not make any attempt to deduce
>     orgname from the server url.
> - Domain name must be specified but it’s    not passed via claims, so it can be anything. Really any non-empty    string o__O
> - Username must be UPN. If it’s not, then, since domain    name is not passed it, ADFS 3.0 throws a fit (ADFS 2.0 assumes the    domain)

The following works for me

```
get-crmconnection -ConnectionString "Server=https://{orgname}.{domain}.com/{orgname}; Domain=this_isnt_used_but_must_be_provided; UserName={domain}\{user}; Password={password}"
```

so does the slightly modified username as UPN

```
get-crmconnection -ConnectionString "Server=https://{orgname}.{domain}.com/{orgname}; Domain=this_isnt_used_but_must_be_provided; UserName={user}@{domain}; Password={password}"
```

Comment: Because I am logging in from domain, I am using the default credentials and can easily omit Domain, Username and Password. I just needed to add the organization name at the end of the URL as you suggested. Thank you.