# Create CrmServiceClient object in plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2016

In Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise IFD, in a plugin, I try to create an object of type Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.**CrmServiceClient**:

```
CrmServiceClient crmSvc = new CrmServiceClient(connString);
```

For connection string I have the following:

*connString = "Url=https://{orgname}.{domain}.com/{orgname}; Domain={domain}; UserName={user}/{domain}; Password={password} AuthType=IFD";*

but when the plugin fires I get the error: 
*Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM OrganizationServiceProxy is null*

The format of connString is customized according to : [Connecting to CRM 2016 IFD in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441610/connecting-to-crm-2016-ifd-in-powershell) 
and the information in connString is correct.

Thank you

Radu

Comment: Is this plugin running in sandbox (aka isolation mode?) If so, does it work if you run it outside the sandbox? Take the connection code and run it in a console application, does it connect? Run the same console app on the CRM server, does it connect? 99% of the time the error you are getting is because there is an issue with the connection string or the CRM server is blocking the traffic (either in the CRM code or the firewall.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to create a new CrmServiceClient using a connection string? You should have everything you need already using the LocalPluginContext passed in the Execute method of your plugin.

See [this page for an explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx) of the context passed to the plugin. You are probably after the Organization Service. Using the `IOrganizationService`, you can create your XRM Context if you need to.

If you show some code, maybe we can help you get connected.